# How to make full screen slider positioned under my nav bar? (Revolution Slider)

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I am wanting to make my full screen revolution slider placed under a nav menu. i.e. I don't want the menu on top of it.

Any suggestions as to what I can try to do this? Can view the website here: [aceaviation.com.au](http://aceaviation.com.au)

Comment: can you show your website link ?

Comment: It's there. Just wasn't a hyperlink sorry.

Comment: please add your nav code and revolution slider shortcode where you call it ?

Comment: It's a template theme. The slider shortcode is placed on the homepage top row. The only thing I could do is put a margin-top on the revo slider, but it's not the best option.

Comment: please can you send me screenshot ?

Comment: Of the homepage layout?
http://i.imgur.com/ijCE208.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117990/discussion-between-raj-kumar-bhardwaj-and-josi).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so remove shortcode revolution slider section from homepage layout you have shown into the screenshot after that go to your theme directory files and 
open header.php and find the code of menu , where div going to close 
paste your revolution slider shortcode like this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[yourslidercode]'); ?>
```

save it and see what happen

Comment: It didn't work, it breaks a little too much of the website as well, I guess I'll just deal with it by making images have some blank space up top :/

Comment: send me screenshot of code where you put it header.php and also provide screenshot  of front end